# Host Geth Mainnet on cloud or use existing mainnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, aws, digitalocean

We are planning to launch our DAPPS Smart Contracts and Token Sale Contracts on mainnet. For testnet we had setup on Digital Ocean. But for mainnet we are confused between to host on our own node on Digital Ocean or AWS or to utilise the service like https://infura.io/?

Is service like Infura reliable to go or better to setup on AWS/Digital Ocean? We will be developing more DAPPS in the future as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've had experience with both and found that sometimes my web3 code would work perfectly with a geth node but then it would fail against Infura. This was about the only issue I found and in the long term if you are building more smart contracts you may as well invest in the knowledge of managing your own geth node.

I am taking this approach as some of my apps need to read a lot of historical data from the blockchain so I can build visualisations related to my app. Having the local geth node makes this far quicker.

I wanted to add, the best testnode I have found is at https://www.rinkeby.io they give you clear directions on how to get test ether and the correct commands to run for your local node. Saved me hours of hunting for the right stuff.